# Vuejs listeners

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating simple app, which will have few listeners. I can't figure out how logic behind that should look like.

HTML:

```
<div id="playerProgressBar">
    <div id="playerHead"></div>
</div>
```

In Vue object i have defined variable:

```
music: document.getElementById('playerHead');
```

My listener should look like this:

```
music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

music.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
    //code
}, false);

function timeUpdate() {
    //code
}
```

So what would be correct way to use listeners in vuejs? Should i use custom directives here? Since I have no event I can't use methods. Putting whole logic in `ready` function doesn't seem to be correct way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## v-on (shorthand: @)

> When used on a normal element, it listens to **native DOM events** only. When used on a custom element component, it also listens to **custom events** emitted on that child component.

So, you could attach an event listener like this:

```
<video @timeupdate="onTimeUpdateListener" src="..."></video>
```

Here is an example where I'm using the [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) library:
https://jsfiddle.net/248nqk02/

Answer (score 5):

This would be the Vue-esque way to assign HTML elements to the app:

```
<video v-el:video-element controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This resolved to a variable `this.$els.videoElement` in the app. More info [here](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el).

Now, to add listeners and functions for them, I'd do something like that:

```
...
ready: function() {
    this.addListeners();
},
methods: {
    addListeners: function() {
        console.log('adding listeners');
        this.$els.videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',this.videoTimeUpdated,false);
    },
    videoTimeUpdated: function() {
        console.log('video time updated');
    }
}
...
```

Obviously, you could put everything video (or any other event related) stuff in a separate [component](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) (not directive, in Vue) to keep the code a bit more neat.