# vuejs with HTML5 audio property

Tags: javascript, html, audio, vue.js

I'm using Vuejs to make a control panel for audio, I want to get the `currentTime` property bind to a `computed` value, so I write

```
  computed: {
    'currentTime': {
      cache: false,
      get: function () {
        return document.getElementById('player').currentTime
      }
    }
  },
```

and here is my `audio` tag:

```
  <audio :src="musicSrc" preload="auto" id="player">
    <p>Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</p>
  </audio>
```

I can get it in `ready`:

```
  ready () {
    this.player = document.getElementById('player')
  },
```

I can control it in `methods`

```
play: function () {
  this.player.play()
},
```

But when I use `{{ currentTime }}` in template I got

> Error when evaluating expression "currentTime".
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTime' of null

Comment: have you tried `this.currentTime`?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 12):

For vue 2.0 the way to reference an element has changed.

In HTML
`<audio ref="audio" controls>`

In Vuejs
`this.currentTime = this.$refs.audio.currentTime`

Answer (score 4):

You should register via v-el to reference it

`<audio v-el:audio :src="musicSrc" preload="auto"></audio>`

then access it in you vue instance via $els property, like so

```
ready: function() {
    this.$els.audio.play();
}
```

Comment: This is now `ref="audio"` and `this.$refs.audio` now, right?

Answer (score 3):

It seems a particularly "vue" way to approach this is like so:

HTML:

```
<audio @timeupdate='onTimeUpdateListener'></audio>
```

JS:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      currentTime: '00:00' // The initial current time
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onTimeUpdateListener: function() {
      // Update current time
      this.currentTime = this.$els.audio.currentTime
    }
  }
}
```

Credit for this approach goes to the author of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35012791/1971662).

Comment: Most correct - no way to be done without @timeupdate .

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3.  this.$refs is no longer available in composition API. You'll need to use the ref() class instead.

```
<audio ref="audio"></audio>
```

```
import { ref } from vue;
export default {
  setup() {
    const audio = ref(null);
    ....
    return {
      audio
  }
}
```