# Playing a sound with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I play a sound with Vue.js?

Seems like I cant just do the regular way.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import AppView from './components/App.vue'

  console.log('Play outside of vue')
  var audio = new Audio('file.mp3')
  audio.play()

  new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    mounted () {
       console.log('Will it play here?? lol')
       var audio = new Audio('file.mp3')
       audio.play()
    }, 
    render: h => h(AppView)
  })
```

As it says Audio is not defined?
Do I have to import it somehow?  Is there a specific vue package for this? or npm package?

I really don't understand, I though Audio was just vanilla javascript?

Comment: It should just work, it's just a native constructor.

Comment: yeah, you would think

Comment: review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713060/vuejs-with-html5-audio-property)

Comment: Just to make sure, you are testing it in browser supporting Audio API, right (i.e. not IE11)? And it has nothing to do with ES6, btw.

Comment: Well what does it have to do with then, if not ES6??  If I take my Vue.js  code, and do it the old way....the above code works fine. No require or import needed.  Just plain old javascript.    But as soon as I put it into ES6 and through a build process.  It doesnt.  Audio, is undefined.  Judging by how I wrestled with google maps and jquery as well.  Im assuming I have to import it somehow?  Either Im getting too old for this shit, or web-design is becoming overly convoluted and way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Well, interesting. What bundler do you use, what build tool? Since Audio is a global symbol it should just be available everywhere. I just tried it in my Vue project and it works (unsurprisingly).

Comment: Im using webpack, and babel (es2015, and stage-2)

Comment: It should work normally - http://jsbin.com/hocijinuga/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I am fully aware that it should.  Thats whats so frustrating.  Its like extra layers of unseen complexity and magic are breaking what should be so simple

Comment: Yeah, but you just give us piece of code that is suposed to work, which it actually does.Could you please give use more code? For instance how you trigger play method ? Also your webpack config should be useful ;)

Comment: Right now Im not even triggering it. Meaning there is no other code.   I just have it in my file, to confirm that it works.  But when I load the page, it says Audio is undefined, is not a constructor.   I'll paste my whole file if you want.

Comment: Okay, so obviously problem is somewhere with transpiling...How your `.babelrc` file looks like ?

Comment: {
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}

Comment: ok well....I got it working.  By doing  new window.Audio('file.mp3') ....  dunno why I didnt try that ages ago lol.  But I still dont fully understand why new Audio() doesnt work when it should.  Unless theres some webpack setting, that makes all global objects need window. infront of it?  But then you would think I would need to do window.alert() and window.confirm()  which I dont need to do

Answer (score 19):

Use `var audio = new Audio(require('./file.mp3'))` this will create the correct path since in `var audio = new Audio('file.mp3')`, your path 'file.mp3' was decoded as a string.

Comment: When you use require, Webpack will ensure the proper path and filename for your audio resource. And don't forget to copy the file in place. I used `const sound = ( new Audio( require('@/assets/foo.ogg') ).play();`, which refers to src/assets in my Vue project.

Answer (score 11):

**** EDITED ****

As the time passed and I developed more using VueJs I'm able to clarify better this issue

The issue was: the audio is being defined out of the scope of VueJs component.
VueJS encapsulates the components in their own context. When we declare it out of new Vue hook, it will be unaware of the existence of this object.

A correct approach would be:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppView from './components/App.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  mounted () {
   console.log('Will it play here?? lol');
   console.log('Play outside of');
   var audio = new Audio('file://path-to-file/file.mp3'); // path to file
   audio.play();
}, 
render: h => h(AppView)
});
```

Also, I should mention that trying to access "file://" in the context of the browser will NOT work, because the browser is sandboxed. You should use an `<input type="file" />` to get the source of the audio, and then put it into the audio variable after manipulate the file itself.

Is worth mention too, that this approach would work much better if you create a global plugin to use on Vue's `this` context. This would make the component reusable and available in every component instance you needed to access allowing you to play or pause the audio from any component source

- [Docs about plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: You can use these demo sounds to test it out: http://www.findsounds.com/ISAPI/search.dll

Comment: for the audio , should we use relative path or absolute path ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use path to audio file related to your script location on your environment

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old. but I thouth it might helps.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import AppView from './components/App.vue'
```

> import audioFile from '@/assets/file.mp3'

```
  console.log('Play outside of vue')
  var audio = new Audio('file.mp3')
  audio.play()

  new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    mounted () {
       console.log('Will it play here?? lol')
       var audio = new Audio('file.mp3')
```

> var audio = new Audio(audioFile)

```
       audio.play()
    }, 
    render: h => h(AppView)
  })
```